# Creating lists of contiguous characters?

Tags: haskell

Basic question, but I can't seem to get a solution that works.

I have the following [Char]:

```
"cdea...x...pwpee"
```

and I wish to covert this to [[Char]]:

```
[[cdea], [x], [pwpee]] --create a lists of contiguous a's
```

My current solution only manages to get the first three a's:

```
myFunction :: [Char] -> [[Char]]
myFunction (x : xs)
  | x == 'a' = [x] : myFunction xs
  | otherwise = []
```

Output:

```
[c,d,e,a]
```

Is there an obvious solution to get the result I intend?

Comment: Try `group "aaaabbbcc"`, after importing `Data.List`

Comment: @chi I've updated the question, this better reflects my problem! group would be ideal if I could pass a custom grouping condition to it

Comment: Description doesn't match the code.  Where are the contiguous `a`s?  If you want to split on `...` check Data.List.Split.splitOn.

Comment: @BabraCunningham Did you see `groupBy`, which is parametric on the condition?

Comment: @chi thank you again, solution found using groupBy!